# Using LIKE with Pro*C

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, oracle-pro-c

How do I use LIKE with Pro*C? The code below doesn't work. I need to search records in database.

```
cout<<"Employee name\t\t: ";
cin.getline(name,50);

EXEC SQL SELECT NAME INTO :nameResult FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE NAME LIKE '%:name%';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a host variable like this: "char hLikeVar[64];".  Then string copy "%[empl name]%" into it.  For [empl name] use the input you got from the user.  Then you can do this:

... WHERE NAME LIKE :hLikeVar;

Comment: How do you string copy it? This code don't worked `strcpy_s(hLikeVar, "%[name]%");` The quote made me confuse on how to get it to work?

Comment: I solved it like this: 

`strcpy (str,"%");
  strcat (str,name);
  strcat (str,"%");

EXEC SQL SELECT NAME INTO :nameResult FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE NAME LIKE :str;`

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

so Pro * C provides `varchar` structures, where you aren't required to handle many things. So if you are declaring

```
varchar LikeVar[Length_of_Variable];
```

and use

```
strcpy(LikeVar.arr); /* .arr is the character array */
LikeVar.len = strlen(LikeVar.arr);
```

after this you can use directly: with in the sql statement.

Comment: Is varchar is structure? why we need to give Length_of_Variable in varchar declaration?

Comment: @Vinoth: As in C programming we have to predefine the length of structure, which is the reason here.

Comment: In c structure we will give the length if we want use the  structure as a array. Consider this case Varchar name[10]. Is Pro *c/c++ allows here to store 10 names as in normal c/c++? I hope this is not possible.